# Java.Lang.Throwable in Mono for Android

Tags: android, mono

The app I'm making downloads avatars used for a friends list. These avatars are cached in order to load them quicker in the future. The cache I created is working, but it throws a load of these exceptions:

```
Enqueued image (0) threads: 1
Error loading image: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Throwable' was thrown.
Enqueued image (0) threads: 1
Error loading image: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Throwable' was thrown.
Enqueued image (0) threads: 1
Error loading image: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Throwable' was thrown.
```

The cache does work however, but still I'd like to have this problem solved.

I'm using Mono for Android, the code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/FlyingPie/SteamDroid/blob/master/SteamDroid2/SteamDroid2/Util/SteamFiles.cs#L161).

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the exception is being thrown because the download url was incorrect. The exception could have been a bit more descriptive. I will contact Xamarin and ask if it should be a proper exception.